# Setting response status code 500 in .aspx page return custom html but with default error message

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to set a custom static error page for 500 internal server error. I am setting 500.aspx page but as soon as i set `Response.StatusCode = 500;` it renders custom 500 page html but also shows error message **The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred** right after `<body>` tag.

Is there a way with which i can only render html with no default error messages.

This is my code currently on `Page_Load()`.

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.Status = "500 Internal server error";
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Response.StatusDescription = "Something went wrong!";
Response.Flush();
```

Would really appreciate responses.

Comment: Have you verified that the code above doesn't throw an exception itself?

Comment: Yes i've verified, there is no exception thrown. It just set the status code of the document to 500.

Comment: Page Load is an event.  So there may be a process running in parallel that is giving the error.

Comment: @jdweng So where can i set `Response.StatusCode = 500;` to return the document with 500 status code ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in Global.asax event `Application_Error` to confirm an application error. You might be able to find out the exact error there as well and trap it. There are answers for doing this online and here.